# Required Content to understand Lang's Algebra from Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

Apologies for the soft question (it seems that I have been asking them most frequently as of late, as I am at something of a mathematical crossroads.)

I am nearing the end of self-studying Abstract Algebra for the first time with Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra,* 10th edition, which I have enjoyed. I intend to read up to Chapter 26 or 27, as the few chapters left after that are mostly "additional material" (a chapter on coding theory, a rather superficial introduction to Galois theory, and some material on cayley digraphs), which although interesting, I would rather study more in-depth later on if the subject ever interests me more seriously.

I am interested, after spending some time learning linear algebra for a second time more rigorously, and to perhaps learn some number theory using Ireland and Rosen, to self-study abstract algebra at a higher level. I am aware that Serge Lang's *Algebra* is the standard of graduate textbooks, and that is my goal. Yet, the normal pathway seems to be along the lines of *Dummit and Foote -> Lang*, and I understand Gallian's book is (quite a bit less) comprehensive that Dummit and Foote. **I was wondering what, as someone who studied with Gallian, I would have to 'fill in on' before moving on to something like Lang's *Algebra,* perhaps with references to chapters in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra (3rd edition).** Or perhaps if there is another textbook other than D&F which I should spend some time on.

If this at all changes something, I'd like to think that I made Gallian as 'rigorous' as it could be, in terms of developing mathematical maturity. I did every exercise in the book (which at times got pedantic, with avg. 70 questions per chapter), and for every theorem presented, tried to prove it myself before looking at the textbook proof. I was able to prove them myself about 85% of the time (although often in a less elegant way than the 'official' proof). In terms of mathematical maturity, I've never self-studied anything at a graduate level, but I have studied analysis using some of the *Princeton Lectures in Analysis* textbooks which is used *sometimes* for graduate studies.

Hopefully this question may assist others in the same position.

Comment: The best suggestion is to just read Lang directly. If you get stuck, then look online for explanation.

Comment: There's also this https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/

Comment: In a way, no one really understands Lang's Algebra ;-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, how so?